# selenium testing with django gives 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python, django, selenium

I cannot see what is making this error happen because it does not give me more information. The tests pass, but they print this message to the console. I will post my files below.

tests.py:

```
class MainAppTests(LiveServerTestCase):
    """Testing the interactions on the main page"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Opening the browser"""
        selenium_logger = logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection')
        # Only display possible problems
        selenium_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.user = make_user()

    def tearDown(self):
        """Closing the browser"""
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_homepage(self):
        """Testing that everything work"""
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertIn("Site", self.browser.title)
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    """View for displaying the home page"""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # Pulling and ordering by the 'full_name' field, shows users what is available
        active_languages = Language.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('full_name')
        context = {'active_languages': active_languages}
        return render(request, 'main/home_loggedin.html', context)
    return render(request, 'main/home_loggedout.html', status=302)
```

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: No, osSierra 10.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not you, it's selenium... :) Your code is correct.

This is a [recent issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2981) with selenium, happening with python client during `self.browser.quit()`.

Updating selenium should do the trick. Although due to the recent nature of the bug (reported and [fixed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9157c7071f9900c2608f5ca40ae4f518ed373b96) on 21th Oct), at the moment, the fix is not yet incorporated the [recent version](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases) of selenium. It should be be fixed on versions above 3.0.1